# Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host: `http://localhost:5000

Tags: jss, jss-rendering-sdk

I am facing an issue on CD server on production, the website is working fine, but there are a lot of errors in the logs that says:

> "[JSS] Error occurred during POST to remote rendering host:
> `http://localhost:5000` 27848 13:31:35 ERROR Unable to connect to the
> remote server".

We are using headless topology: so the node server is separated from CD. I checked the configuration I found that this URL (http://localhost:5000) is coming from  **Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.config** file, the EndpointUrl.

not sure if this file is required on CD server, I disabled it and it didn't impact the running website, but it shows another errors in the log file for GetFactory configuration. seems it's being called from somewhere.

I also tried to change the EndpointUrl to point to the rendering host URL, that I have on the node proxy server, but it didn't work looks like, it's expecting only **http** not **https**. but all communications between servers are https. I really appreciate any suggestion to avoid this error. or at least show me example of on how I can use endpoint URL with https.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="ContentManagement or ContentDelivery or Standalone">
    <javaScriptServices>
      <renderEngines>
        <renderEngine name="http">
          <instance id="defaults">
            <!-- Specifies the endpoint where Layout Service data and function arguments will be sent during JSS rendering. -->
            <EndpointUrl>http://localhost:5000</EndpointUrl>
            <!--
              Specifies the URL that will be used when creating absolute links in the rendered HTML.
              Link replacement is necessary in order for relative links in the rendered HTML to be able to load in the Experience Editor.
              If not specificied (default), link replacement will not be performed.
            -->
            <ApplicationUrl></ApplicationUrl>
            <!-- Specifies the maximum duration, in milliseconds, that your .NET code should wait for requests to the HTTP renderer (e.g. the `EndpointUrl` setting) to respond. -->
            <RequestTimeoutMs>10000</RequestTimeoutMs>
            <!-- Serialization settings to use when serializing the JSON payload that is sent to the HTTP renderer endpoint URL. -->
            <JsonSerializerSettings type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.DefaultJsonSerializerSettings, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http" />
            <!--
              Determines whether or not the render engine options can be overridden by request-specific (or other provided) values.
              By default, only `EndpointUrl` is eligible to be overridden, but other options may be enabled via customization.
              Example: `EndpointUrl` setting can be overridden via querystring parameter, e.g. `?sc_httprenderengineurl=http://myhost.com`
              Important: This setting is intended for development purposes only and should be disabled (false) for any non-development environments.
             -->
            <AllowOptionsOverride role:require="ContentDelivery">false</AllowOptionsOverride>
            <AllowOptionsOverride role:require="ContentManagement or Standalone">true</AllowOptionsOverride>
            <!--Specifies if Relative Link Processing will be enabled in the Experience Editor. -->
            <EnableRelativeLinkProcessing>true</EnableRelativeLinkProcessing>
          </instance>
        </renderEngine>
      </renderEngines>
    </javaScriptServices>
    <pipelines>
      <group groupName="javaScriptServices">
        <pipelines>
          <getRenderEngineFactory>
            <processor type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.Pipelines.GetRenderEngineFactory.GetHttpEngineFactory, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http" resolve="true" />
          </getRenderEngineFactory>
        </pipelines>
      </group>
    </pipelines>
    <services>
      <configurator type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.RegisterDependencies, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http" />
    </services>
    <settings>
      <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="$(env:SITECORE_JSS_EDITING_SECRET)" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: What didn't work when you updated the EndpointUrl?